# What is the point of the ".list" files on the releases.ubuntu.com pages?

Tags: 14.04, downloads

On the main release page (http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/), listed along with the iso files for Ubuntu 14.04, there are several ".list" files, including ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.list. The contents of these files look like this:

```
...
/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_018-2_i386.deb
/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5_all.deb
/pool/main/f/fakeroot/fakeroot_1.20-3ubuntu2_i386.deb
/pool/main/f/fakeroot/libfakeroot_1.20-3ubuntu2_i386.deb
...
```

I attempted to downloaded all the files on one of these lists (in an effort to manually install Ubuntu), but some of the files in the list are not available on ftp.ubuntu.com. If these are not lists of the required packages for Ubuntu, then what are they for?  If they are, why are some of the files listed not on ftp.ubuntu.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These files are meta files for the respected .iso. It contains lists all the files and packages present in the iso file.

You can find all these packages  in the the Ubuntu  repository, but file other than the packages are not present on the repository.