# PHP version on Ubuntu Server 14.04.4 LTS

Tags: 14.04, server, php, versions

I would like know what specific version of PHP is installed* on stated Ubuntu server.
I have read that 14.04.4 upgraded to PHP 5.5, however I need to know if the PHP version is >=5.5.9.

I have failed to find any information regarding the specific version (with the last number), I presume It's because the distributed PHP is beign updated, and thus it is not in Ubuntu release doc.

Thank you

*without manual updates, "out of the box"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.4/release/ there are "**.list**" files with the list of included packages in "Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (Trusty Tahr)". As is explained in the "Ask Ubuntu" answer, by the user [g_p](https://askubuntu.com/users/146791/g-p), to the [What is the point of the ".list" files on the releases.ubuntu.com pages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531536/what-is-the-point-of-the-list-files-on-the-releases-ubuntu-com-pages) question, those .list files "(...) *lists all the files and packages present in the iso file.*"

The relevant ".list" file for the files and packages contained in the Ubuntu Server 14.04.4 LTS (I assume that you're talking about the 64-bit version) ISO is http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.4/release/ubuntu-14.04.4-server-amd64+mac.list

By opening that ".list" file, we see that the PHP (PHP5) ".deb" packages listed are in version **5.5.9** (the version in the "php5" package itself is probably the best indicator). So, "5.5.9" would be the version included in that release.

Below, for reference, I include some of the packages included in that ".list" file:

> (...)
>   /pool/main/p/php5/libapache2-mod-php5_**5.5.9**+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14_amd64.deb
>   (...)
>   /pool/main/p/php5/php-pear_**5.5.9**+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14_all.deb
>   /pool/main/p/php5/php5-cgi_**5.5.9**+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14_amd64.deb
>   /pool/main/p/php5/php5-cli_**5.5.9**+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14_amd64.deb
>   /pool/main/p/php5/php5-common_**5.5.9**+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14_amd64.deb
>   (...)
>   /pool/main/p/php5/php5_**5.5.9**+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14_all.deb